# External web service callout

Tags: apex, soap-api, integration, soap

I have parsed a WSDL i obtained from 3rd party application that i want to integrate with Salesforce.

Wsdltoapex created 3 apex classes for me. I'm stumped on what i'm supposed to do next. Do i need to modify those classes at all? How do i make the callout? I need data changes from the 3rd party app to update Salesforce data.

I read over the SOAP integration guide but it wasn't too clear how to actually make the callout.

Answer (score 0):

1. first install SoapUi tool in your system.
2. create a new project by importing WSDL obtained by 3rd party.
3. after importing WSDL it will show all methods available for callout.
4. select method, set the header  value like user id, password, tocken as per requirement  and make request.
5. you will get responce for your request
6. test all methods till you fiend your required response
7. go to your org import WSDL and make call to that method

SoapUi is best tool for testing WSDL file, you can download it from http://www.soapui.org/downloads/soapui-open-source.html

Comment: This does not really answer the OP's question. If the OP does not know where to start to even use the WSDL then there is no way doing it in the SoapUI will help him do it in apex....

Comment: As mention above OP's has already parsed WSDL file and created apex classes, next thing he need to know is which operation is available and which operation to call and what param needed for that operation which he will easily get by SoapUi.